# Finding optimal value of $\omega$ to solve this linear system

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I have the following problem.

Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$  matrix with $a_{ii}\not= 0$, $i = 1,\dots,n$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$. We write $A=L+D+U$, where $D$ is diagonal, $L$ is strictly lower triangular and $U$ is strictly upper triangular.

We want to solve $Ax = b$ by using the following iterative method:

$$x^{(k+1)} = B_\omega x^{(k)} + c\omega, \quad \omega > 0.$$
where
$$B_\omega = (1 − \omega)I − \omega D^{−1}(L + U),\qquad c_\omega = \omega D^{−1}b$$

Suppose the Jacobi method is convergent and that $B_J$ (iteration matrix of Jacobi method) has only real eigenvalues
$$\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2\leq\dots\leq\lambda_n$$
Prove that the optimal value of $\omega$ is $\omega_{opt} = \frac{2}{(2 − \lambda_1 − \lambda_n)}$. Which is the value of $\rho(B_{\omega_{opt}})$?

I already proved that if the Jacobi method is convergent, we need $0<\omega<1$. Moreover,
I found that $λ$ is an eigenvalue of $B_J$  iff $1 − \omega + \omega\lambda$ is
an eigenvalue of $B_\omega$. However, I do not know how to find the optimum value of $\omega$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just search for "successive over-relaxation" (SOR).

Comment: I know about SOR methods, and I know the existence of a theorem for tridiagonal matrices. However, this is not the case. Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: This is not SOR, this is modified Jacobi method. SOR is an extension of Gauss-Seidel just like this method is an extension of Jacobi method

Comment: Are the diagonal entries of your matrix $A$ really zero as you explicitly write? It seems that $D$ consistent of the diagonal entries and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just some hints to proceed.

1. If $B_J$ has real eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \leqslant \dots \leqslant \lambda_n$ what is the spectral radius $\rho(B_J)$?
2. If $\mu_k$ are eigenvalues of $B_\omega$ then $1 - \mu_k = \omega (1 - \lambda_k)$ (this is what you've already found). Now, knowing the eigenvalues of $B_\omega$, what is the spectral radius $\rho(B_\omega)$? You might want to plot $\lambda_k$ vs $\mu_k$ for different values of $\omega$.
3. How is convergence related to the spectral radius of the iteration matrix $B$?